# Sorting IQueryable by Collection items as a string

Tags: c#, .net

Can't figure out how to sort my IQueryable by Collection property

I had a users list. Each user can present in multiple groups, that are concantenated and listed as strings:

administrators, operators, managers...etc

xaml code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
       Binding="{Binding User.Groups, Converter= converters:UserGroupsToStringConverter}}"
       Header="Groups"
       SortMemberPath="User.Groups" />
```

I handle sorting event for custom sorting and can't find a way to sort by collection items:

```
q = SortDirection
            ? q.OrderBy(p => p.User.Groups)
            : q.OrderByDescending(p => p.User.Groups);
```

Where User.Groups is of type `List<Group>`

Tryed Join, ToString, magic... any advice?

Comment: How do you expect your Groups (collections) should be compared? Please firstly define criteria. For example, you may define that the groups are not equal, but prioritized, so that a user should appear at the top of the list if there is group "administrators" among that user's groups. With this approach you could compare the collections in this way: (a) find the most important group in each collection, (b) compare these two groups, (c) sort the list of users accordingly to the comparison results.

Comment: I expect, comparing user group names as strings, sorted asc or desc. like user1: administrators, user2: administrators, operators, user3:operators etc... So my goal is to interprete them as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I can conclude you probably need something like this:
    q.OrderBy( p => ( from g in p.User.Groups orderby g.Name select g.Name ).Agregate( (a, g) => a + "," + g ) )

Comment: thanks for advice! but i examined that sorting of collection is not reachable in linq to sql in my case.